# Trying to figure out a way to get my Twitter bot to tweet users based on requested dates

Tags: python, tweepy

I've managed to get my bot to parse it's mentions for the proper method of requesting a date. For example, if a user mentions my bot with "Reminder 09/20/2019" or any other random date, it'll respond with Date Test Successful.

The problem i'm currently having is that I want my bot to only respond to the mention(s) **on the date requested**. For example, if a user mentions my bot with "Reminder 10/1/2019", I want my bot to respond with "Date Test Succesful" on 10/1/2019.

If my problem isn't explained clear enough, I can go more in depth.

The code i'm currently working with is here:

```
> # Extended tweet mode is for showing longer tweets in mentions
    mentions = api.mentions_timeline(tweet_mode='extended')
    for tweets in reversed(mentions):
        date_search_match = re.compile(r"(?:reminder|Reminder)\s\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}")
        if date_search_match.search(tweets.full_text)
            api.update_status(f"@{tweets.user.screen_name} Date Test Successful")
```

Comment: "respond to the requested date on the date requested"???

Comment: You can store the dates in a database and then once a day query for reminders by using a python scheduling package like this one:  https://github.com/dbader/schedule .  Or you can run a python script on a `cron` job.

Comment: @KevinWelch mistake, edited

Comment: I'm actually familiar with schedule by Daniel, thanks man. Will look into it @j3py

Answer (score 0):

You can store the dates in a database and then once a day query for reminders by using a python scheduling package like this one: github.com/dbader/schedule .

For example:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm searching the DB for today's reminders...")
    <logic for querying the DB>
    print("and tweeting out the reminders...")
    <logic for tweeting the reminders with tweepy>

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Or you can run a python script on a `cron` job.